# how can use JavaScript to control audio in the embed tag

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Start & Stop & Pause buttons are working but I can't control audio scroll-bar
This my code >>> the goal of my code is to control two audios in the same time without using html5

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
            function play() {
                window.document.embeds[0].Play()
                window.document.embeds[1].Play()
            }
            function stop() {
                window.document.embeds[0].Stop()
                window.document.embeds[1].Stop()
            }
            function start() {
                window.document.embeds[0].Rewind()
                window.document.embeds[1].Rewind()
            }
            function forward() {
                window.document.embeds[0].Forward();
                window.document.embeds[1].Forward();
            }
            function forward() {
                window.document.embeds[0].forward();
                window.document.embeds[1].forward();
            }
            function forward() {
                window.document.embeds[0].back();
                window.document.embeds[1].back();
            }
        </SCRIPT>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY onLoad="start()">
    <EMBED SRC="Sound/Egypt.wav" NAME="video" AUTOSTART="false">
        <EMBED SRC= "Sound/Madina.wav" AUTOSTART="false">
            <FORM>
                <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Reset" onClick="start()">
                <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Play" onClick="play()">
                <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="Pause" onClick="stop()">
                <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE="<<" onClick="forward()">
                <INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=">>" onClick="backward()">
            </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: not sure if this can be done without HTML5. Why not go for it ?

Comment: as html5 not works with all browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
function ScrollSound(time){
    var x = document.getElementById("first");               
    x.SetTime(time+ x.GetTime());
    var y = document.getElementById("second");
    y.SetTime(time+ y.GetTime());
}
```